# Scipy minimize with constrain for whole data set and all values except zero

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, statistics, minimize

I try to get the parameter of an statistic equation to my data via the *most log-likelihoode* method. The equation I want to fit with the constrains looks like that:
[Equation and Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyE5s.png)

The best fit is achieved at the minimum of my likelihood-function *l*

A minimal Example would look like that:

```py
import numpy as np

from numpy import log
from scipy.optimize import minimize

y =np.array([0.21863326, 0.19805154, 0.22953017, 0.21906749, 0.22067327,
       0.20638931, 0.17845443, 0.20008429, 0.21702199, 0.16334912,
       0.18480577, 0.17172182, 0.16495525, 0.15907978, 0.17029919,
       0.14020628, 0.16528562, 0.17141436, 0.14978351, 0.1329871 ,
       0.14036109, 0.15894933, 0.16783223, 0.17372222, 0.15986161,
       0.1654368 , 0.16348146, 0.15595923, 0.15192792, 0.12272897,
       0.17252942, 0.17164107, 0.16064716, 0.14564287, 0.14578649,
       0.14152733, 0.1354919 , 0.11175379, 0.1380746 , 0.12547517,
       0.15136653, 0.13984282, 0.18308302, 0.12271885, 0.15289988,
       0.13492309, 0.13499516, 0.13373476, 0.1034279 , 0.14278288,
       0.14574681, 0.11614764, 0.11256923, 0.14796558, 0.11459825,
       0.12417535, 0.15693744, 0.14159134, 0.11885544, 0.13164357,
       0.13445257, 0.13527885, 0.13472062, 0.12027512, 0.12072214,
       0.15361264, 0.12973932, 0.11003032, 0.13575847, 0.11980422,
       0.1187932 , 0.11152574, 0.14656588, 0.13885414, 0.13960315,
       0.12921241, 0.09522926, 0.14543513, 0.14980696, 0.11318417,
       0.10785905, 0.13858491, 0.11922434, 0.11760534, 0.12059705,
       0.12150726, 0.1184712 , 0.11084933, 0.10894509, 0.10107464,
       0.10258616, 0.1094653 , 0.095096  , 0.10059849, 0.10931144,
       0.11704954, 0.12639652, 0.13283708, 0.10203757, 0.10787873])

def l(para,args):
    xi,sigma = para
    y = args
    k = len(y)
    SUM = log(1+(xi*y)/sigma)
    return (-k*log(sigma)-(1+xi)/xi*np.sum(SUM))

def constrain1(x):
    xi,sigma = x
    return sigma
def constrain2(x):
    xi,sigma = x
    return -xi
def constrain3(x,*args):
    xi,sigma = x
    yi = args
    return 1+xi*yi/sigma
    

con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constrain1}
con2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constrain2}
con3 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constrain3,'args': y}
cons = [con1,con2,con3]

x0 =(-0.1,2)   
bound =((-np.inf,None),(None,np.inf))
res = minimize(l,x0,(y),bounds = bound,constraints=cons)
```

The first problem I've got is to implement *constrain 3* that the term inside the logarithm  is greater than zero for every data point (***1+(xi y_i)/sigma>0***). I tried to add the constrains in a for-loop

```py
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constrain1}
con2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constrain2}
cons = [con1,con2]
for yi in y:
    con3 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constrain3,'args': yi}
    cons.append(con3)
```

but that didn't work neither.

My second issue is that the constraints just support ***>=*** or ***=***. Is there a way to implement just ***>*** and especially not equal (***!=***)? I want ***xi != 0*** and ***sigma > 0***. I am quiete suprised that I didn't find anything regarding that topic since this should be a standard problem in mathematics or I didn't look hard enough

I found a workaround for that in mathlab where i did one optimization with ***xi<=0*** and another one with ***xi>=0*** and chose the better fit. ***sigma*** doesn't seem to be influenced that much by the constrain that it could be zero. But I would prefer a solution where I do not have to do an evaulation between to different solutions.

Comment: Some remarks: strict inequalities are not supported and do not make much sense in most optimization-frameworks in theory. Explicit *epsilon-based* formulation is needed (`>= 0 + eps`) and you must decide if  *epsilon* is `10^-100` or `10^-2`. `scipy.minimize` is mostly about numerical-optimization (and in best-case: convex), but `x != 0` divides the space into a non-convex set / disjunction and you cannot do this without branching / discrete-optimization techniques. Simplified speaking: you ask for things which would allow us to solve all those NP-hard problems easily. There must be a catch.

Comment: The path to chose is often very use-case depending and some knowledge surely helps. Without context and by purely looking at your equations, i would just say, that the `x != 0` is constraint is a hack to avoid division-by-zero and should never be handled as branched-inequality. In scipy optimize, you probably would just catch this case and do some sub-gradient like stuff. If that's working out is another story though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @sascha . You are right. It sounded to simple that there wouldn't be a catch.
I try to fit a generaized pareto distribution to my data in the context of a statistical extrem value evalutaion and the constrain ` xi!=0 ` is indeed there so you can't devide by zero. It's my first try using ` scipy.minimize ` and my math background is limited to an engineering point of view. How should I implement that in my code?

Comment: I would ignore it and not use an initial-start where this value is *not* set to zero. Chances that it gets zero are pretty slim (and even this could be handlded within your function with some if; losing smoothness there hopefully does not kill the solver). You have to experiment a bit. I could imagine you will run into more than one numerical problem including some need for episilon tuning for sigma. Furthermore, if it's non-convex (not sure), you probably want to use multiple-starts too.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

from numpy import log
from scipy.optimize import minimize

y = np.array([0.21863326, 0.19805154, 0.22953017, 0.21906749, 0.22067327,
              0.20638931, 0.17845443, 0.20008429, 0.21702199, 0.16334912,
              0.18480577, 0.17172182, 0.16495525, 0.15907978, 0.17029919,
              0.14020628, 0.16528562, 0.17141436, 0.14978351, 0.1329871,
              0.14036109, 0.15894933, 0.16783223, 0.17372222, 0.15986161,
              0.1654368, 0.16348146, 0.15595923, 0.15192792, 0.12272897,
              0.17252942, 0.17164107, 0.16064716, 0.14564287, 0.14578649,
              0.14152733, 0.1354919, 0.11175379, 0.1380746, 0.12547517,
              0.15136653, 0.13984282, 0.18308302, 0.12271885, 0.15289988,
              0.13492309, 0.13499516, 0.13373476, 0.1034279, 0.14278288,
              0.14574681, 0.11614764, 0.11256923, 0.14796558, 0.11459825,
              0.12417535, 0.15693744, 0.14159134, 0.11885544, 0.13164357,
              0.13445257, 0.13527885, 0.13472062, 0.12027512, 0.12072214,
              0.15361264, 0.12973932, 0.11003032, 0.13575847, 0.11980422,
              0.1187932, 0.11152574, 0.14656588, 0.13885414, 0.13960315,
              0.12921241, 0.09522926, 0.14543513, 0.14980696, 0.11318417,
              0.10785905, 0.13858491, 0.11922434, 0.11760534, 0.12059705,
              0.12150726, 0.1184712, 0.11084933, 0.10894509, 0.10107464,
              0.10258616, 0.1094653, 0.095096, 0.10059849, 0.10931144,
              0.11704954, 0.12639652, 0.13283708, 0.10203757, 0.10787873])


def l(para, args):
    xi, sigma = para
    y = args
    k = len(y)
    # Define a list of functions to use np.sum() on
    SUM = [log(1 + (xi * y_i) / sigma) for y_i in y]
    return -k * log(sigma) - (1 + xi) / xi * np.sum(SUM)


def constrain1(x):
    (xi, sigma) = x
    return sigma


def constrain2(x):
    xi, sigma = x
    return -xi


# Use a class to prevent the python garbage collector to kick in
class Constraint3:
    def __init__(self, y_i):
        self.y_i = y_i

    def make_constraint(self, x):
        xi, sigma = x
        return 1 + xi * self.y_i / sigma


con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constrain1}
con2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constrain2}
constraints_list = [con1, con2]

for y_i in y:
    # Make each constraint function unique by instantiating the above class with the
    # new y_i value. The usage of individually defined function is not advised, because
    # some of them could get garbage collected, when there are too many items in the
    # array.
    constraints_list.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': Constraint3(y_i).make_constraint})

# Use proper ndarray-type
x0 = np.array([-0.1, 2])
bound = ((-np.inf, None), (None, np.inf))

res = minimize(l, x0, y, bounds=bound, constraints=constraints_list,
               options={'disp': True})
print("            Parameter values:")
print("              xi:   ", res.x[0])
print("              sigma:", res.x[1])

# Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
#         Current function value: -1739.2412627695364
#         Iterations: 24
#         Function evaluations: 82
#         Gradient evaluations: 24
#         Parameter values:
#           xi:    -1928.571453953235
#           sigma: 35762853.400437616
```